# Turn off summary row from DevExpress XtraGrid

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtragrid

Ever since we upgraded to 13.2.7 version of DevExpress, a summary row has been added to the Detail view of several Xtragrids that have master-detail.

I have been trying to figure out how I can turn the summary row off, but cannot seem to find the correct property.  Hoping someone can help me get this turned off.

Image of grid:

[image]

Comment: Not sure, but this may [help](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridOptionsView_GroupFooterShowModetopic)

Comment: Thanks Sriram, but I have tried this as well as setting OptionsView.ShowFooter to false... neither are making a difference.  I am also able to turn off the 'Change In Balance' sum and see that it goes away, but the summary row still shows.

Comment: I believe you'll get better support in devexpress for corner cases like this. Did you tried?

Comment: I have searched in DevEx for the answer, but have not posted a support issue because I will need to track down the registered login info for my company.  Was hoping this would be something easy enough that there would be someone with a quick answer, but it looks like I might just have to go that route.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible way that you may have added Summary row ( present in `DevExpress.XtraGrid.StyleFormatCondition` class ) to your code:

**1. From the code :**

If you add `Summary row` from code then you simply remove the code which look like -

```
GridColumnSummaryItem s1 = new GridColumnSummaryItem();
            s1.SummaryType = DevExpress.Data.SummaryItemType.Sum;
            s1.DisplayFormat = "Payable Amount : {0:n5}";
```

**2. From the Designew :**

If you have added `Summary row` from the Designer then follow this steps-

1. Select your GridControle and Run Designer
2. Then select the column name under 'Column' option from the side bar Select "SummaryItem" and
3. romeve the selected option from this property.

Please take help of this image.

[Image 1: Follow marked steps to solve using designer if used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iT7wl.png)

Answer (score 0):

Handle the `GridView.CustomSummaryExists` event to prevent specific summary items from being calculated for group rows.

Link : https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CustomDrawGroupRowtopic

and   http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q98247